# Regex incapsulate things not insinde brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

my goal is, as the title says to incapsulate everything not inside brackets inside brackets like this:

```
@tdWrap@ something here @tdWrapEnd@
```

This is what i have so far:

```
var str = '1+[2/3]-23+2+<3,4,[22/7]+2;2,3,4>+2';

var indices = str.split(/\[[^\]]*\]|<[^>]*>/);

var tdWrapper = [];

for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    tdWrapper[i] = '@tdWrap@' + indices[i] + '@tdWrapEnd@'
}
for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    indices[i] = indices[i].replace(/([\+\-\*\?])/g, '\\$1')
}


var regObj;
for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    regObj = new RegExp(indices[i]);
    str = str.replace(regObj, tdWrapper[i])
}
```

The problem is that when i replace in the string there a duplicates, so i can´t replace the correct things. This is the string i want to end up with:

```
@tdWrap@1+@tdWrapEnd@[2/3]@tdWrap@-23+2+@tdWrapEnd@<3,4,[22/7]+2;2,3,4>@tdWrap@+2@tdWrapEnd@
```

But this is the string i end up with:

```
@tdWrap@1+@tdWrapEnd@[2/3]@tdWrap@-23@tdWrap@+2@tdWrapEnd@+@tdWrapEnd@<3,4,[22/7]+2;2,3,4>+2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the `replace` method and a closure. You need to put all you want to skip in a capture group to return it as it:

```
var str = '1+[2/3]-23+2+<3,4,[22/7]+2;2,3,4>+2';

var result = str.replace(/[0-9+*\/-]+|(\[[^\]]*\]|<[^>]*>)/g, function (m, g1) {
    if (g1 == undefined) return '@tdWrap@' + m + '@tdWrapEnd@';
    return g1;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @VictorVH: Note that I didn't put the question mark inside the character class because I didn't understand why it must be here, but If you need it, you can add it.

Comment: How is the function getting called? and what are m and g1?

Comment: @VictorVH: the function is called on each match, `m` contains the whole match result, and `g1` contains the first capturing group result. When the pattern succeeds with something that is between angle or square brackets, the first capturing group (and g1) is defined and the group content is returned.

Comment: Thank you. You have been very helpful. Do you have any documentation on this? I can´t seem to find any

Comment: @VictorVH: yes the official documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace